# Outputting multiple combinations

Tags: c++

I am trying to output all of these variables in a certain order abc acb bac bca cab cba but it only outputs `xyz xzy yxz yzx zxy zyx` instead of `#$% #%$ $#% $%# %#$ %$#` and `123 132 213 231 312 321` as well. How do I make it so it outputs `xyz xzy yxz yzx zxy zyx` and `#$% #%$ $#% $%# %#$ %$#` and `123 132 213 231 312 321` when it tests for those values?

Output all combinations of character variables a, b, and c, in the order shown below. If `a = 'x', b = 'y', and c = 'z'`, then the output is: `xyz xzy yxz yzx zxy zyx`

Your code will be tested in three different programs, with a, b, c assigned with 'x', 'y', 'z', then with '#', '$', '%', then with '1', '2', '3'.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   char a;
   char b;
   char c;

   cin >> a;
   cin >> b;
   cin >> c;

   a = 'x'; 
   b = 'y'; 
   c = 'z';

   cout << a << b << c << " ";
   cout << a << c << b << " ";
   cout << b << a << c << " ";
   cout << b << c << a << " ";
   cout << c << a << b << " ";
   cout << c << b << a << "";

   cout << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, I think, you don't need to assign some values to your variables after an input

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

this is a basic variable assignment question. you can basically read the input and print the variable and it will print whichever value is assigned to the variable. The code snippet below is in Java but it gives you an idea of how to just print the variable in different combination as requested. The whole program is given below.

```
public class OutputCombinations {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      char a;
      char b;
      char c;

      a = scnr.next().charAt(0);
      b = scnr.next().charAt(0);
      c = scnr.next().charAt(0);

      System.out.print(""+a+b+c+" "+a+c+b+" "+b+a+c+" "+b+c+a+" "+c+a+b+" "+c+b+a);

      System.out.println("");
   }
}
```

this is not how programming works in real world, but this is just for assignment. while we learn and explore further, we could recursively print them based on the number of inputs received.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

We have 2 problems here.

1. You do not understand the question
2. You do not yet know and understand the programming language

Let us start with the question.

- The teacher wants to understand you what a permutation is
- You should start thinking about loops (What if it is not only xyz, but all 26 characters?)
- Your program will be tested with different input. No need to assign something to a, b or c.

The program will be invoked and then somebody (the somebody is a computer) enters the test data.

So, if you would delete the lines:

```
    a = 'x'; '#'; '1';
    b = 'y'; '$'; '2';
    c = 'z'; '%'; '3';
```

then you have already a working solution.

Those lines are anyway wrong. Or what do you expect what the statement `'2';` should do.

For that reason, you need to read more text books.

I could now explain about `std::array` or `std::vector` or `std::next_permutation`, but you would anyway not understand it.

So, please continue to study.

Comment: Please note that the lines you are discussing are not in the question (anymore).

Comment: Right. Was edited. But the question will be closed anyway . . .

Comment: If you are convinced that a question will be or should be closed, then do not answer and flag/close vote instead. (Admittedly I was a little late in retracting my close-vote, thanks for making me notice.)

Answer (score 0):

After you read the input in here:

```
cin >> a;
cin >> b;
cin >> c;
```

You overwrite it immediatly with constant here:

```
   a = 'x'; 
   b = 'y'; 
   c = 'z';
```

That makes your program ignore the input.
Delete those lines and the program should correcty work with the input by user.

You seem (in comments) to be thinking of those assignments as "initialising", but they are not, because they are AFTER the first use of those variables for storing input.